# ExtJS 5 - Model disable automatic field creation

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2, extjs5

Is it possible to disable automatic field creation introduced in ExtJS-5?

Just doesn't work well with our existing 4.2 app and we are hoping to upgrade to 5 without having to make wholesale changes to the application

Thanks

Comment: I don't *think* there's a way to do this. What problems are you having - maybe there's another way to workaround it.

Comment: I agree with Colin, can you explain why this is causing problems for your app? Then we can assist you in solving those problems